# What is similar to -k / --insecure of CURL for Nodejs?

Tags: node.js, ssl, curl, https

I have a https connection to make in nodejs and the certificate and keys are not compatible with a CA so need to ignore the host/domain name verification check like the `--insecure/-k` flag of curl tool.

I tried the request in curl and its working. The same thing I need to implement in Nodejs env.
The library I am using is `https`.
What extra options should I use for the same?

Comment: Tried that already, still no luck Giving 400 BAD REQUEST from the server.

Comment: That means it worked. Otherwise your server wouldn't even have had a chance to receive the request. Why your server is returning error 400 is therefore no longer in the scope of this question.